# Line chart not showing in PrimeFaces chart with time in Y-axis

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

PrimeFaces: 6.0.0

I would like to display line chart. In that chart,

X-Axis should display Sce_1, Sce_2.... etc.,
Y-Axis should display Time in HH:MM:SS format

Currently, I could display values in both x-Axis, but the chart is not displayed.

**Chart :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3fL8.png)

Following is my code:

**In Xhtml file:**

```
<p:chart  id="gp2" type="line" model="#{student.areaModel}" extender="ext2" style="height:400px;width:800px" />
```

**Java Script:**
**Note: I have imported jqplot-1.4.20.jar in my project**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/org/wicketstuff/jqplot/behavior/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function ext2() {
        //this = chart widget instance
        //this.cfg = options
        this.cfg.axes = {
            xaxis : {

                rendererOptions : {
                    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                },
                tickOptions : {
                    fontSize : '10pt',
                    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
                    angle : 30
                }
            },
            yaxis : {
                min : null,
                max : null,
                autoscale : true,
                numberTicks : null,
                pad : 1.0,
                tickInterval : '1 days',
                renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions : {
                    tickInset : 0
                },
                tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions : {
                    fontSize : '10pt',
                    fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
                    angle : -40
                }
            }
        };
        this.cfg.highlighter = {
            show : true,
            tooltipOffset : 2
        }
    };
    //]]>
</script>
```

In Backingbean file,

```
public void graph_04()
    {
        if(areaModel != null)
        {
            areaModel.clear();
        }
        areaModel = new LineChartModel();


        DateAxis Yaxis = new DateAxis("Time");
        Yaxis.setMin("00:00:00");
        Yaxis.setMax("00:59:59");
        Yaxis.setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S");
        areaModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.Y, Yaxis);


        Axis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Sce Name");
        areaModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
        xAxis.setTickAngle(-30);
        areaModel.setStacked(true);
        areaModel.setShowPointLabels(true);

        LineChartSeries ch = new LineChartSeries();
        ch.setLabel("List");
        ch.set("Sce_1", new Time(00,10,10).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_2", new Time(00,20,10).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_3", new Time(00,30,12).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_4", new Time(00,40,18).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_5", new Time(00,50,56).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_6", new Time(00,22,30).getTime());
        ch.set("Sce_7", new Time(00,18,40).getTime());

        areaModel.addSeries(ch);    
    }
```

Why chart value is not displaying in chart?

Comment: PF Version? Are you **100% sure** the extender is used (read PrimeFaces User Guide 3.15.15 Extender)?

Comment: Its PF version 6.0.0 and I am not sure how to use extender but followed some blog post and done that. If you can identify whether i have used correctly or not then it would be great

Comment: You use a pre 5.3 way of using the extender... From the 6.0 docs (3.15.15)  _"where model's extender property is set to "ext"."_ It should be set on the model (via java), not on the tag (xhtml).

Comment: I have tried and when I do that my y-axis change shows today's date but not time.

Comment: Then search how you should get a time in the axis (keep in mind that you configured a **Date**AxisRenderer and an interval of 1 day !!!